# Configurando porta no tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

Estou desenvolvendo vários serviços e estes são executados na porta 8080 pelo tomcat.

Como os próximos serviços a serem gerados não tem relação com os serviços que já foram gerados, foi requisitado que a porta fosse modificada.

Achei a classe `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` que modifica a porta do tomcat pelo java.

Fiz esse código para modificar a porta:

```
public class TestContext {

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {

        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        factory.setPort(2020);

        factory.addInitializers();

        return factory;
    }

}
```

O serviço é executado normalmente e a porta está sendo modificada, só que o mapeamento dos serviços não está sendo feito.

Eu queria um exemplo de como utilizar esta classe para fazer o mapeamento. Pelo menos qual método eu tenho que usar para fazer o mapeamento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução que encontrei foi criar um file `application.properties` dentro do diretorio `src/main/resources` com o código `server.port = 2020.`

O mapeamento dos serviços é feito corretamente e a porta é modificada.